# Database Migration IBM AIX to windows

Tags: mysql, database, migration, database-migration

Database migration people,

We are trying to migrate MySql5.0 databases from IBM AIX boxes to Windows 2012 server environment.
There are php, java and .net applications that hit these databases.

When we moved couple of databases that php and java use. we got errors for php applications,when inserting or updatinga table saying , "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'customer_id' at row 1”.
In our case MySQL is trying to assign an empty 
string to an auto-increment INT field.

We dont want to  make changes in the php code. But is there a way i can set 
My Sql modes on my.ini file on windows to handle this well.

For the java applications, for the datetime column, if the empty dates come in , it has to either set it as null or insert something
as atleast this "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
As i said earlier, We dont to make changes in java application.

can this be set on my.ini file on SQL modes, so that the migration of mysql between AIX environment and windows, does not need code changes in short term atleast.

Im not a data base administrator. Please be easy on me.

Comment: Compare the mysql versions first, I bet they differ. Then read the release notes; eg for 5.7: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/

Comment: Oh yes! discovered they are different.Thank you.But if i want to keep the version and move on, can there be any setting change in my.ini file?

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation... Migration between DB-versions is always problematic, don't do it on the production system without proper tests.

Comment: Thank you...we are thoroughly testing it ....